# How exactly does __attribute__((constructor)) work?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, gcc

It seems pretty clear that it is supposed to set things up.

1. When exactly does it run?
2. Why are there two parentheses?
3. Is `__attribute__` a function? A macro? Syntax?
4. Does this work in C? C++?
5. Does the function it works with need to be static?
6. When does `__attribute__((destructor))` run?

[Example in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046426/initialising-a-static-variable-in-objective-c-category/2046997#2046997):

```
__attribute__((constructor))
static void initialize_navigationBarImages() {
  navigationBarImages = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

__attribute__((destructor))
static void destroy_navigationBarImages() {
  [navigationBarImages release];
}
```

Answer (score 352, accepted):

1. It runs when a shared library is loaded, typically during program startup.
2. That's how all GCC attributes are; presumably to distinguish them from function calls.
3. GCC-specific syntax.
4. Yes, this works in C and C++.
5. No, the function does not need to be static.
6. The destructor runs when the shared library is unloaded, typically at program exit.

So, the way the constructors and destructors work is that the shared object file contains special sections (.ctors and .dtors on ELF) which contain references to the functions marked with the constructor and destructor attributes, respectively. When the library is loaded/unloaded the dynamic loader program (ld.so or somesuch) checks whether such sections exist, and if so, calls the functions referenced therein.

Come to think of it, there is probably some similar magic in the normal static linker so that the same code is run on startup/shutdown regardless if the user chooses static or dynamic linking.

Comment: The double brackets make them easy to "macro out" (`#define __attribute__(x)`). If you have multiple attributes, e.g., `__attribute__((noreturn, weak))`, it'd be hard to "macro out" if there were only one set of brackets.

Comment: It isn't done with `.init/.fini`.  (You can validly have multiple constructors and destructors in a single translation unit, nevermind multiple in a single library -- how would that work?)  Instead, on platforms using ELF binary format (Linux, etc.), the constructors and destructors are referenced in the `.ctors` and `.dtors` sections of the header.  True, in the old days, functions named `init` and `fini` would be run on dynamic library load and unload if they existed, but that's deprecated now, replaced by this better mechanism.

Comment: @ephemient: Thanks, I had forgot about the new and improved way of doing things. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: FYI: In the gcc online documents (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) it says the following under "constructor, destructor": "These attributes are not currently implemented for Objective-C."

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: `#define __attribute__(x, ...)` would work well in that case, with no added complexity.

Comment: @jcayzac No, because variadic macros is a gcc extension, and the main reason for macroing out `__attribute__` is if you're not using gcc, since that, too, is a gcc extension.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young variadic macros are a standard C99 feature, not a GNU extension.

Comment: @jcayzac Before C99, back when `__attribute__` was first invented, guess which C compilers had to be supported.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young of course back then the double parentheses were needed, I wasn't questioning that. I just wanted to point out your use of present tense ("make" instead of "made, "it'd be" instead of "it'd have been"…). C99 is 13 years old.

Comment: @jcayzac C99 is 13 years old, but C++11 is not. ;-) Many header files are written for C++ compatibility too, and there are still many, many programs that are written for C++98. So I'd still say that the use of the present tense remains justified, for a great number of programs still in maintenance.

Comment: "your use of present tense ("make" instead of "made" -- the double parens **still** make them easy to macro out. You barked up the wrong pedantic tree.

Comment: how can the loader call those functions? those functions can use globals and other functions in the process address space, but loader is a process with its own address space, isnt it?

Comment: @user2162550 the runtime linker/loader runs in the same process and address space as the dynamically linked binaries and libraries it loads.

Comment: According to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46770, starting from GCC 4.7.0 `__attribute__((constructor))` uses the `.init_array` section instead of the `.ctors` section, and similarly for `.fini_array` instead of `.dtors`.

Comment: What about multithreading while initialization functions are executed are they protected by mutexes?

Comment: @uuu777 The glibc manual states that dlopen() and dlcose() are MT-safe, however POSIX doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 75):

`.init`/`.fini` isn't deprecated. It's still part of the the ELF standard and I'd dare say it will be forever. Code in `.init`/`.fini` is run by the loader/runtime-linker when code is loaded/unloaded. I.e. on each ELF load (for example a shared library) code in `.init` will be run. It's still possible to use that mechanism to achieve about the same thing as with    `__attribute__((constructor))/((destructor))`. It's old-school but it has some benefits.

`.ctors`/`.dtors` mechanism for example require support by system-rtl/loader/linker-script. This is far from certain to be available on all systems, for example deeply embedded systems where code executes on bare metal. I.e. even if `__attribute__((constructor))/((destructor))` is supported by GCC, it's not certain it will run as it's up to the linker to organize it and to the loader (or in some cases, boot-code) to run it. To use `.init`/`.fini` instead, the easiest way is to use linker flags: -init & -fini (i.e. from GCC command line, syntax would be `-Wl -init my_init -fini my_fini`).

On system supporting both methods, one possible benefit is that code in `.init` is run before `.ctors` and code in `.fini` after `.dtors`. If order is relevant that's at least one crude but easy way to distinguish between init/exit functions.

A major drawback is that you can't easily have more than one `_init` and one `_fini` function per each loadable module and would probably have to fragment code in more `.so` than motivated. Another is that when using the linker method described above, one replaces the original _init and `_fini` default functions (provided by `crti.o`). This is where all sorts of initialization usually occur (on Linux this is where global variable assignment is initialized). A way around that is described [here](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Calling_A_Function_At_ELF_Shared_Library_Load_Time.shtml)

Notice in the link above that a cascading to the original `_init()` is not needed as it's still in place. The `call` in the inline assembly however is x86-mnemonic and calling a function from assembly would look completely different for many other architectures (like ARM for example). I.e. code is not transparent.

`.init`/`.fini` and `.ctors`/`.detors` mechanisms are similar, but not quite. Code in `.init`/`.fini` runs "as is". I.e. you can have several functions in `.init`/`.fini`, but it is AFAIK syntactically difficult to put them there fully transparently in pure C without breaking up code in many small `.so` files.

`.ctors`/`.dtors` are differently organized than `.init`/`.fini`. `.ctors`/`.dtors` sections are both just tables with pointers to functions, and the "caller" is a system-provided loop that calls each function indirectly. I.e. the loop-caller can be architecture specific, but as it's part of the system (if it exists at all i.e.) it doesn't matter.

The following snippet adds new function pointers to the `.ctors` function array, principally the same way as `__attribute__((constructor))` does (method can coexist with `__attribute__((constructor)))`.

```
#define SECTION( S ) __attribute__ ((section ( S )))
void test(void) {
   printf("Hello\n");
}
void (*funcptr)(void) SECTION(".ctors") =test;
void (*funcptr2)(void) SECTION(".ctors") =test;
void (*funcptr3)(void) SECTION(".dtors") =test;
```

One can also add the function pointers to a completely different self-invented section. A modified linker script and an additional function mimicking the loader `.ctors`/`.dtors` loop is needed in such case. But with it one can achieve better control over execution order, add in-argument and return code handling e.t.a. (In a C++ project for example, it would be useful if in need of something running before or after global constructors).

I'd prefer `__attribute__((constructor))/((destructor))` where possible, it's a simple and elegant solution even it feels like cheating. For bare-metal coders like myself, this is just not always an option.

Some good reference in the book [*Linkers & loaders*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604960).

Comment: how can the loader call those functions? those functions can use globals and other functions in the process address space, but loader is a process with its own address space, isnt it?

Comment: @user2162550 No, ld-linux.so.2 (the usual "interpreter", the loader for dynamic libraries that runs on all dynamically linked executables) runs in the very address space of the executable itself. In general the dynamic library loader itself is something specific to the userspace, running in the context of the thread that tries to access a library resource.

Comment: When I call execv() from the code that has `__attribute__((constructor))/((destructor))` the destructor does not run. I tried few things such as adding an entry to .dtor as shown above.  But no success.  The problem is easy to duplicate by running the code with numactl.  For example, assume test_code contains the destructor (add a printf to the constructor and desctructor functions to debug the problem). Then run `LD_PRELOAD=./test_code numactl -N 0 sleep 1`.  You will see that the constructor is called twice but destructor only once.

Comment: @ljleb Link updated.

Comment: @izac89 It's implementation specific how the loader works. On Linux as PaulStelian mentions, it's part of the process but it's not a process itself. You don't need to know how it works, just that the convention for picking up CTOR/DTOR functions is appending to a table of function pointers that reside in sections .ctor/.dtor. On a fully fledged OS (like Linux) appending to this list is all that's needed.

Answer (score 56):

This page provides great understanding about the `constructor` and `destructor` attribute implementation and the sections within within ELF that allow them to work. After digesting the information provided here, I compiled a bit of additional information and (borrowing the section example from Michael Ambrus above) created an example to illustrate the concepts and help my learning. Those results are provided below along with the example source.

As explained in this thread, the `constructor` and `destructor` attributes create entries in the `.ctors` and `.dtors` section of the object file. You can place references to functions in either section in one of three ways. (1) using either the `section` attribute; (2) `constructor` and `destructor` attributes or (3) with an inline-assembly call (as referenced the link in Ambrus' answer).

The use of `constructor` and `destructor` attributes allow you to additionally assign a priority to the constructor/destructor to control its order of execution before `main()` is called or after it returns. The lower the priority value given, the higher the execution priority (lower priorities execute before higher priorities before main() -- and subsequent to higher priorities after main() ). The priority values you give **must be greater than`100`** as the compiler reserves priority values between 0-100 for implementation. A`constructor` or `destructor` specified with priority executes before a `constructor` or `destructor` specified without priority.

With the 'section' attribute or with inline-assembly, you can also place function references in the `.init` and `.fini` ELF code section that will execute before any constructor and after any destructor, respectively. Any functions called by the function reference placed in the `.init` section, will execute before the function reference itself (as usual).

I have tried to illustrate each of those in the example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*  test function utilizing attribute 'section' ".ctors"/".dtors"
    to create constuctors/destructors without assigned priority.
    (provided by Michael Ambrus in earlier answer)
*/

#define SECTION( S ) __attribute__ ((section ( S )))

void test (void) {
printf("\n\ttest() utilizing -- (.section .ctors/.dtors) w/o priority\n");
}

void (*funcptr1)(void) SECTION(".ctors") =test;
void (*funcptr2)(void) SECTION(".ctors") =test;
void (*funcptr3)(void) SECTION(".dtors") =test;

/*  functions constructX, destructX use attributes 'constructor' and
    'destructor' to create prioritized entries in the .ctors, .dtors
    ELF sections, respectively.
    
    NOTE: priorities 0-100 are reserved
*/
void construct1 () __attribute__ ((constructor (101)));
void construct2 () __attribute__ ((constructor (102)));
void destruct1 () __attribute__ ((destructor (101)));
void destruct2 () __attribute__ ((destructor (102)));

/*  init_some_function() - called by elf_init()
*/
int init_some_function () {
    printf ("\n  init_some_function() called by elf_init()\n");
    return 1;
}

/*  elf_init uses inline-assembly to place itself in the ELF .init section.
*/
int elf_init (void)
{
    __asm__ (".section .init \n call elf_init \n .section .text\n");

    if(!init_some_function ())
    {
        exit (1);
    }
    
    printf ("\n    elf_init() -- (.section .init)\n");

    return 1;
}

/*
    function definitions for constructX and destructX
*/
void construct1 () {
    printf ("\n      construct1() constructor -- (.section .ctors) priority 101\n");
}

void construct2 () {
    printf ("\n      construct2() constructor -- (.section .ctors) priority 102\n");
}

void destruct1 () {
    printf ("\n      destruct1() destructor -- (.section .dtors) priority 101\n\n");
}

void destruct2 () {
    printf ("\n      destruct2() destructor -- (.section .dtors) priority 102\n");
}

/* main makes no function call to any of the functions declared above
*/
int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf ("\n\t  [ main body of program ]\n");

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
init_some_function() called by elf_init()

    elf_init() -- (.section .init)

    construct1() constructor -- (.section .ctors) priority 101

    construct2() constructor -- (.section .ctors) priority 102

        test() utilizing -- (.section .ctors/.dtors) w/o priority

        test() utilizing -- (.section .ctors/.dtors) w/o priority

        [ main body of program ]

        test() utilizing -- (.section .ctors/.dtors) w/o priority

    destruct2() destructor -- (.section .dtors) priority 102

    destruct1() destructor -- (.section .dtors) priority 101
```

The example helped cement the constructor/destructor behavior, hopefully it will be useful to others as well.

Comment: Where did you find that "the priority values you give must be greater than 100"? That information isn't present on the [GCC function attributes documentation.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

Comment: IIRC, there were a couple of references, [**PATCH: Support priority argument for constructor/destructor arguments**](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2007-02/msg01950.html)(`MAX_RESERVED_INIT_PRIORITY`), and that they were the same as **C++** (`init_priority`) [**7.7 C++-Specific Variable, Function, and Type Attributes**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html). Then I tried it with `99`: `warning: constructor priorities from 0 to 100 are reserved for the implementation [enabled by default] void construct0 () __attribute__ ((constructor (99)));`.

Comment: Ah. I tried priorities < 100 with clang and it seemed to be working, but my simple test case (a single compilation unit) [was too simple](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2012-April/022952.html).

Comment: What is the priority of static global variables (static ctors)?

Comment: The effect and visibility of a *static global* will depend on how your program is structured (e.g single file, multiple files (*translation units*)) and in which the global is declared [**See: Static (keyword)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_%28keyword%29), specifically the **Static global variable** description.

Comment: So this is the best overview I have found so far. One question: How is the .init section order determined/which .init routine runs first? I got hosed by another package calling my routines before the constructors ran, so I believe it was an .init section routine that did it (and of course it crashed with a segfault). Sounds like I need to be at the top of the .init list.

Comment: @ScottFranco if you use the `section` attribute or *inline assembly* to place a function reference in the `.init` section of the ELF executable, then that function will be called before any function placed in an object file by either method or with `constructor` attribute. If you write more than one call in the `.init` section, then the functions would be called in the order placed. A second call simply adds another `call somefunction` entry in the ELF `.init` section.

Comment: For example if you add a second `int elf_init2 (void)` function below the original `int elf_init(void)` it will be called after the original `elf_init` but before any of the functions declared with the `constructor` attribute.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a "concrete" (and *possibly useful*) example of *how, why, and when* to use these handy, yet **unsightly** constructs...

Xcode uses a "global" "user default" to decide which `XCTestObserver` class *spews it's heart out* to the *beleaguered* console.

In this example... when I implicitly load this psuedo-library, let's call it... `libdemure.a`, via a flag in my test target á la..

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ldemure
```

I want to..

1. At load (ie. when `XCTest` loads my test bundle), override the "default" `XCTest` "observer" class... (via the `constructor` function) PS: As far as I can tell.. anything done here could be done with equivalent effect inside my class' `+ (void) load { ... }` method.
2. run my tests.... in this case, with less inane verbosity in the logs (implementation upon request)
3. Return the "global" `XCTestObserver` class to it's pristine state.. so as not to foul up other `XCTest` runs which haven't gotten on the bandwagon (aka. linked to `libdemure.a`). I guess this historically was done in `dealloc`.. but I'm not about to start messing with that old hag.

So...

```
#define USER_DEFS NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults

@interface      DemureTestObserver : XCTestObserver @end
@implementation DemureTestObserver

__attribute__((constructor)) static void hijack_observer() {

/*! here I totally hijack the default logging, but you CAN
    use multiple observers, just CSV them, 
    i.e. "@"DemureTestObserverm,XCTestLog"
*/
  [USER_DEFS setObject:@"DemureTestObserver" 
                forKey:@"XCTestObserverClass"];
  [USER_DEFS synchronize];
}

__attribute__((destructor)) static void reset_observer()  {

  // Clean up, and it's as if we had never been here.
  [USER_DEFS setObject:@"XCTestLog" 
                forKey:@"XCTestObserverClass"];
  [USER_DEFS synchronize];
}

...
@end
```

Without the linker flag... (Fashion-police swarm Cupertino **demanding retribution**, yet Apple's default prevails, *as is desired, here*)

[image]

WITH the `-ldemure.a` linker flag... (Comprehensible results, *gasp*... "thanks `constructor`/`destructor`"... *Crowd cheers*)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another concrete example. It is for a shared library. The shared library's main function is to communicate with a smart card reader, but it can also receive 'configuration information' at runtime over UDP. The UDP is handled by a thread which **MUST** be started at init time.

```
__attribute__((constructor))  static void startUdpReceiveThread (void) {
    pthread_create( &tid_udpthread, NULL, __feigh_udp_receive_loop, NULL );
    return;
    
  }
```

The library was written in C.