# LINUX: order of statically linked module loading

Tags: module, linux-kernel

If I have two modules which are being statically linked in.  One modules' module_init function depends on another module's module_init function having already run.  Is there a way to force one module to load before the other?

Also, is the first module's init function guaranteed to finish before the second one is invoked?

Lastly, if the answer to the above is NO, what is the recommended way of synchronizing the two module init calls to make sure I don't run into issues?

Comment: 1) Which language/toolchain, 2) Do you mean linked to a .so or a .a?

Comment: Do you mean two Linux kernel modules? How are they statically linked in? You can't statically link two objects together both with a "module_init" function.

Comment: I believe owen has it, seeing as the `module_init` symbol is an integral part of the Linux kernel module system.  @John  you should edit your question and include the `linux-kernel` tag - the `linux` tag is (unfortunately) dominated by userspace issues, often not even Linux specific.

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a way to force one module to load before the other?

Answer is surprisingly simple, make sure first module is first in Makefile:

```
obj-y += mod1.o
obj-y += mod2.o
```

> is the first module's init function guaranteed to finish before the second one is invoked?

Yes, initcalls (`module_init` hook) in your case are called one-by-one. See `init/main.c`,
`do_one_initcall()` callers.

Comment: This solution won't work for modules defined in different Makefiles.
Any solution for the case that the two modules are compiled in different Makefiles?

Comment: @talel Generally there is a top Makefile to define the sequence to descend into directories and an arch Makefile to define arch-specific sections. You can look for those init-y, core-y, drivers-y etc. in those Makefiles. Also this article may be helpful to you.
http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to fix the static initialization fiasco

Have a look at

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html (**init_priority**)
- [How exactly does __attribute__((constructor)) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work/2053078#2053078)
- the -rdynamic linker flag for gcc/ld (this gives you some latitude to do compile time linking, and still use the runtime loader (dload))

[Static Initialization Order Fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)

Comment: He's talking about Linux kernel modules; your solutions all have to do with C++ userspace.

Comment: @Eric: oops, thanks for noticing - I missed that completely... I assumed the strange names (module_init) where on some kind of exotic UNIX flavour :)