# module_platform_driver initialization order

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, initialization, kernel-module

I'm adding in some thermal code to Linux. I have found that this code at one point assumes that CPUFreq has already been initialized. Both of these drivers are initialized via module_platform_driver. Currently module_platform_driver(therm) is called before module_platform_driver(cpufreq). Is it possible to change the initialization order to make sure that module_platform_driver(therm) is called after module_platform_driver(cpufreq)? Or do I need to change the thermal driver to use device_initcall, which is ordered later, but doesn't have the nice "platform_driver" wrapper?

Comment: You want to ensure *static* module initialization order? Where would those two modules (the cpufreq and thermal ones) be found in the kernel tree?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I'd like to ensure static module initialization order. In the device-tree the CPUFreq is the first and the thermal is at the end.

Comment: This doesn't matter, because devices are probably added by the architecture-specific initialization code *before* driver modules are loaded. Then, the static driver initialization order matters. You didn't answer my question. I wasn't talking about the *device tree*, but about the *kernel tree*. Where would your module sources (cpufreq and thermal modules) be in the kernel source tree?

Comment: @eepp The kernel tree module locations are drivers/cpufreq and drivers/thermal. When I view the make output the cpufreq obj file is created before the thermal obj file.

Comment: @ChristianMuller Have you considered using late_initcall()?  See this for an example: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/keyboard/gpio_keys.c?v=3.9#L879

Comment: @PeterL. - Thanks for the comment. Yes, I may have to, I was trying to maintain consistency with my other drivers and keep using `module_platform_driver()`, but if I cannot change the order, I will pursue the `late_initcall` route.

Comment: And I believe you cannot find any example of a thermal driver using cpufreq? The ordering of built-in kernel modules at the same init level is determined by linking, and therefore by the Makefiles themselves. If you cannot find any existing similar case in the mainline kernel, perhaps you have a new use case. Verify in the current source if having cpufreq drivers initialized before thermal ones will be a problem. If not, submit a patch that's putting cpufreq before thermal in `drivers/Makefile` (thermal is currently before cpufreq) and explain why you want to do this.

Comment: @eepp - Thanks the drivers/Makefile orders answers my question. I was thinking there may have been some kernel software change I could do, but the linker is where this order comes from. The exynos_thermal from Linaro does this, I'm not sure why it doesn't show an issue. I'll do more homework, but this issue is closed for me.

Answer (score 0):

to order the initialization, you can put each of them in the difference init phase.
refer to old topic:
[How does Linux determine the order of module init calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368837/how-does-linux-determine-the-order-of-module-init-calls)