# How to force Linux mmcblk enumeration

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

On my device I have *2 mmc devices*, eMMC and an SD card, which the Kernel enumerates as `/dev/mmcblk0` and `/dev/mmcblk1` respectively. It would be desirable for it to enumerate these the other way around,

So does anyone know of a way to force this as a kernel parameter of some kind?

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669647/linux-order-of-statically-linked-module-loading (requires rebuild)

Comment: However, is there a real reason to force the kernel to load them in reverse order? I believe in many userspaces will let you configure which device get mounted. (even Android, via `vold.fstab`)

Comment: tell the purpose, not the result you think you want to achieve; you can change udev rules but I think this is not the easy way you want

Comment: The purpose is that I want ideally to not modify the Android images (system.img/ramdisk.img.ub) in any way, and am looking for a method that allows me to force this from within the Kernel/Kernel parameters. We have a method that works by changing the images, but I want to keep the images essentially agnostic, and move the responsibility to the platform to ensure the desired mount device is blk0. This would mean you could boot from eMMC or SD, with the same images, by changing the enumeration order.

Comment: FYI, the vold.fstab option was actually pretty close to the truth, it is one of a few files that need to be modified in Android to achieve this.