# .so: need to find out which function(s) are executed on loading

Tags: linux, gcc, android-ndk, shared-libraries, posix

In [Automatically executed functions when loading shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759880/automatically-executed-functions-when-loading-shared-libraries) we read:

*To have a function executed whenever the shared library is loaded or unloaded, you can mark a constructor and destructor function using GCC-specific attribute syntax:*

```
__attribute__((constructor)) void init(void) { ... }
__attribute__((destructor))  void fini(void) { ... }
```

The article [How exactly does __attribute__((constructor)) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work) also mentions `.init/.fini`.

Now, I have a `.so` module (a shared object library, no source) and I want to know which function(s) are executed when the library is loaded/unloaded. I tried `nm`, but it looks like these attributes are not shown in the output.

So, ***How do I know which function(s) are automatically executed when the shared library is loaded or unloaded?***

Comment: You need to tear apart the sections and disassemble them.

Comment: Quick idea: create a minimal dll with a constructor/destructor, and get a symbol list with a command nm --dynamic test.lib.so .

Comment: Take a look at `objdump --disassemble-all --section=.ctors lib.so`. It should contain addresses of the functions, which are executed when the shared library is loaded.

Comment: If the library is a `dlopen`-ed plugin, the loading application has its own conventions and will use `dlsym`

Answer (score 0):

I still have no general-case answer, but this is what I found:

The library has sections `.init_array` and `.fini_array`. (There's no `.init` or `.ctors`, but YMMV.)

```
; Segment type: Pure data
            AREA .init_array, DATA
            DCD sub_F5C+1
            DCB    0
            DCB    0
            DCB    0
            DCB    0
.init_array   ends
```

So it looks like `sub_F5C()` is the only function invoked while initializing. The 4 zero bytes at the end are really one zero dword; +1 is an ARM feature to select the instruction set.

[More about `.init_array` and other special sections](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.sheader.html#special_sections)