# Influence dlopen() search path after application startup. Possible?

Tags: linux, loader, dlopen

I have some non-accessible code that I call, that does `dlopen("lib.so",  RTLD_LOCAL)`.

The problem is that I need to control the search path of dlopen(). The answer to this problem is quite typically "set LD_LIBRARY_PATH", but I don't know the actual path to set until after application startup, so I can't put a wrapper script that sets it and then invokes my application.

According to the documentation of ld.so and of dlopen, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is only examined at application startup. If you change it afterwards inside the application with setenv, it won't change the lookup list of dlopen().

I know that specifying the full path to dlopen() would be a strategy, but I don't have access to that dlopen call, so this option is also not possible.

Am I out of options or is there some magic strategy I can't find?

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear. Are you just using that code, or can you change some of the source code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not easily possible.

<sup>However, if you are crazy enough to patch `ld.so` from its source code, you might do something.</sup>

Maybe you could use some `LD_PRELOAD` trick.

But if it is a matter of finding which exact file is `dlopen`-ed, why don't you [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) your program to understand which files are `mmap`-ed?

You can also use `pmap` or simply `cat /proc/$(pidof your-program)/maps`

If you can change some lines of source code, consider [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) to find out where is some `dlsym`-ed function... And you might also use [dl_iterate_phdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html)

Comment: It's a long story. I tried to make it easy, but the true need is because I need to override libncurses with libncursesw (wide char support) in a python application. The _curses module binds against libncurses, so what I do is that I copy libncursesw as libncurses in a user-accessible dir, then override the search path and import _curses so that it resolves against the curses with wide char support. It was just a curiosity to make my code more user friendly, but I can find out alternative strategies...

Comment: You should have told that in your question. I would believe you should handle that in python.

Comment: I can't handle that in python. _curses.so is linked to libncurses.so. which is a system lib, so I can't touch it. My question is generic because my scope is well defined: override dlopen search strategy after startup. If I solve that, I solve my specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is relative to your application root - you can use wrapper script, which will extract path to itself using `$(dirname $0)` and set up correct `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Another trick (but it's not a good idea to do so) is to provide your own `lib.so` that will be just a proxy to actual lib.so. You can initialize all references on your proxy library load using library init functionality. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759880/automatically-executed-functions-when-loading-shared-libraries) question.