# system() function not called from LD_PRELOAD'ed library

Tags: c++, linux, ld-preload

I am trying to use `LD_PRELOAD` on linux to wrap calls to `system` function to add some preprocessing to the argument. Here's my `system.cpp`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*orig_system_type)(const char *command);

int system(const char *command)
{
    std::string new_cmd = std::string("set -f;") + command;
    // next line is for debuggin only
    std::cout << new_cmd << std::endl;

    orig_system_type orig_system;
    orig_system = (orig_system_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"system");
    return orig_system(new_cmd.c_str());
}
```

I build it with

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -ldl -o libsystem.so system.cpp
```

which produces the .so object.  I then run my program with

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libsystem.so ./myprogram
```

I do not get any errors - but seemingly my `system` function is not called.  Running with `LD_DEBUG=libs`, I can see that my .so is being loaded, however my `system` function is not being called and the one from the standard library is called instead.

What do I need to change in code/build to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
extern "C" int system ...
```

because it is called by a C function. The C++ version has its name mangled so it is not recognizable.

Comment: Yes! that was it.  I did wonder about name mangling, as `strings libsystem.so | grep system` had some mangling around the `system` function name.  With the `extern "C"` it works correctly now!

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to consider saving the "orig_system" pointer so that you avoid calling dlsym every time. You can do this in a [constructor/init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759880/automatically-executed-functions-when-loading-shared-libraries) function, so you would have something like

```
extern "C" {

typedef int (*orig_system_type)(const char *command);

static orig_system_type orig_system;

static void myInit() __attribute__((constructor));

void myInit()
{
    orig_system = (orig_system_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"system");
}

int system(const char *command)
{
    std::string new_cmd = std::string("set -f;") + command;
    // next line is for debuggin only
    std::cout << new_cmd << std::endl;
    return orig_system(new_cmd.c_str());
}

}
```

(this code isn't tested, but I have used this technique in the past).

An alternative would be to use GNU ld's --wrap option.

If you compile your shared lib with

-Wl,--wrap system

then in your code you write

```
extern "C" {

void* __real_system(const char* command);
void* __wrap_system(const char* command)
{
    std::string new_cmd = std::string("set -f;") + command;
    // next line is for debuggin only
    std::cout << new_cmd << std::endl;
    return __real_system(new_cmd.c_str());
}

}
```

(Note that I've never used this).

Answer (score 0):

The code should work perfectly fine. Assuming the driver program is something like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    system("find -name *.cpp");
}
```

Then `env LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/libsystem.so ./a.out` gives me this output:

```
set -f;find -name *.cpp
./system.cpp
./test.cpp
```

Which shows that not only is your debug statement appearing, but that glob is disabled for that command.

Comment: See @rici answer - you are correct, it would correctly if the driver program is in C, but in my case it's c++ and name mangling gets in the way.