# Calling (void)load from viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to load web data asynchronously. I understand that I can use the following, but I don't know how to call the void(load) method. How do I call this? It doesn't appear to be called automatically. Thanks!

```
- (void)load
{
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL 
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: 1. Maybe `[self load];`? 2. Why do you expect this to be called automatically?

Comment: Why do you expect this method to be called automatically?

Comment: I think you're thinking of the _class_ method `load`, which isn't a suitable place for this sort of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like H2CO3 said, you should call the method by using [self load].  I would expect you want to call it in the method -(void)viewDidLoad.  This is called once for when the view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
__attribute__((constructor)) 
- (void)load
{
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL 
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

> It's run when a shared library is loaded, typically during program
>   startup.

Take a look at [How exactly does __attribute__((constructor)) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work)