# How can I create a static NSString[] of static NSString constants?

Tags: objective-c, static, nsstring, nsarray, constants

I have a collection of static NSString consts in one of my header files that I would like to utilize in a new static NSArray (or NSString[]) but am running into the following error

```
Initializer Element is not a compile-time constant
```

My strings and array are set up as follows:

```
static NSString * const SOMEVAL = @"val";
static NSString * const SOMEKEY = @"key";

static NSString *KEYLIST[] = { SOMEVAL, SOMEKEY };
```

Is it possible to get this static array to compile in this manner or will the previously declared NSStrings always show up as non-compile-time constants?

Comment: Note that `static NSString *KEYLIST[]` is not describing an NSArray.

Comment: Updated title to reflect @HotLicks comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will never treat objects as "compile-time constants"; you will have to do one of two workarounds.

You can use preprocessor definitions for the strings:

```
#define KEY @"key"
#define VAL @"val"

static NSString * const key = KEY;
static NSString * const val = VAL;

static NSString * keyVal[] = { KEY, VAL };
```

Or you can initialize the array in a function or method which is guaranteed to be called before you need the array. The [`constructor` function attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work) is one option:

```
static NSString * keyVal[2];

__attribute__((constructor))
void setKeyVal(void)
{
    keyVal[0] = key;
    keyVal[1] = val;
}
```

The [`+initialize` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-initialize) of a closely-related class is another.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use static in a header file. In the header declare:

```
extern NSString * const SOMEVAL;
extern NSString * const SOMEKEY;

extern NSString *KEYLIST[];
```

and then in a source file define:

```
NSString * const SOMEVAL = @"val";
NSString * const SOMEKEY = @"key";

NSString *KEYLIST[] = { SOMEVAL, SOMEKEY };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to rely on the compiler combining identical string constants (a pretty safe bet), you can do this instead:

```
#define SOMEVAL @"val"
#define SOMEKEY @"key"

static NSString *KEYLIST[] = { SOMEVAL, SOMEKEY };
```