# How to run Objective-C file in the beginning of Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to use objective-c in swift project.I want to use [THIS](https://github.com/icepat/ICETutorial) library of objective-c in swift.I imported this library in my swift project.I want this library to run in the beginning when I build my project,but when I build my project,ViewController.swift is being run.So,how do I run the library in the beginning?

Comment: You can also try the same library in Swift: https://github.com/icepat/ICETutorialSwift

Comment: Did you ran this library of swift?every page seems dislocated

Answer (score 1):

In objective C you can have a class with a `+(void)load` method... this will get run very early, maybe before everything is set up... you can also investigate the  [`constructor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work) attribute.