# Does static initialization (and/or other) code get run when dlopen'ing?

Tags: c++, dlopen, shared-objects, dynamic-loading, static-initialization

When you `dlopen()` a shared object, is there a mechanism for having code in that DLL execute without being called explicitly? Specifically, C++ static initialization code for globals/statics which the caller of `dlopen()` might not know about? I'm pretty sure the answer should be "yes" but I don't remember what mechanism makes that happen, and how to utilize it for running arbitrary code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work

Comment: @Brian: I think you can make that an answer... although - what if I don't use GCC? e.g. clang or icc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: `dlopen` respects an ELF binary format mechanism for running code at load time.

There are actually two such mechanisms:

- An older one uses special `.init` and `.fini`s sections, which contain an array of function pointers for `dlopen` and `dlclose` to call. Since the sections may not be present at runtime, there are also `DT_INIT` and `DT_FINI` dynamic tags which point to the corresponding sections.
- The newer mechanism is `.init_array` and `.fini_array` and corresponding `DT_INIT_ARRAY`, `DT_INIT_ARRAYSZ`, `DT_FINI_ARRAY` and `DT_FINI_ARRAYSZ` dynamic tags.

The difference between the two mechanisms is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-7529/6mdhf5r2s/index.html).

Going up to the source code level, if you decorate a C function with  `__attribute__((constructor))`, the compiler will use one of those two mechanisms to make it run when the object is `dlopen`ed. The same goes for the construction code for global C++ objects requiring dynamic initialization.