# LLVM how to execute code in a module before any other code

Tags: llvm

I want to instrument some code that gets executed before any other code in my module.

I thought about calling the code in the start of the main function. But there is not always a main function or it is not always named "main". Or it is a library and it doesn't even have a main function.

Are there some other, smarter ways?

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#the-llvm-global-ctors-global-variable

Comment: @IsmailBadawi that seems to be a good answer. Do you have any idea how I can append to this variable from an compiler pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the code you want to run early into a function and add that function to [`llvm.global_ctors`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#the-llvm-global-ctors-global-variable). This is the equivalent of using [`__attribute__((constructor))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work) in C or C++.

To do this from a pass, you can use the [`llvm::appendToGlobalCtors`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#ae85c8b3bbab3831fdbb0a4eddebddcdf) function, which is declared in `llvm/Transforms/Utils/ModuleUtils.h`.