# How to run function on ending a C++ Command Line App?

Tags: c++, command-line, command-line-interface

I know this probably already has an answer on here, but basically I need to close a session on the server when the Command Line is force closed.

Comment: [`std::atexit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) and [`std::at_quick_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/at_quick_exit) come to mind. But there is no way to ensure you always run something so the server should implement a timeout mechanism. If the user kills the program via other means it may not run exit handlers

Comment: See [How exactly does __attribute__((constructor)) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361145/3422102) for additional methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use a C++ destructor. At the beginning of your main(), define a variable with a session class like below.

```
class ManageSession
{
public:
   int sessionId;
   ManageSession() {
      sessionId = Connect();
   }
   ~ManageSession()
   {
      Close(sessionId);
   }

   int Connect() {
      // find and connect
      return 42;
   }
   void Close(int id) {
      if (id > 0) {
         id = 0; // close it
      }
   }
};

int main() {
   ManageSession session;

   // do amazing things
};
```

Comment: This will only work if the program exits in a controlled fashion (i.e returns from main(), one way or the other).  If the program is simply killed (or calls `exit()` or `_exit()`, the ManageSession destructor will never execute.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Yes, adding an exception handler in main an/or using set_terminate() function will allow some processing on unexpected exits.