# Right way to initialize a static library (C++)?

Tags: c++

I have a static C library that I want to port to C++, in the C library I got some global variables that store some common data used by the functions for example:

```
// global variable in the C library
int global_number_of_cpu_cores;

init_global_vars()
{
    global_number_of_cpu_cores = get_info();
}
    
void lib_function()
{
    // use global_number_of_cpu_cores
}
```

when using the library, it must be first initialized by the init function but in C++, the object's constructors are executed before the main function, so I cannot code:

```
class class_lib
{
    class_lib()
    {
         // use global_number_of_cpu_cores but this is uninitialized!
    }
}
```

Also, you can initialize global variables with functions:

```
int program_var = lib_function(); // lib_function uses global_number_of_cpu_cores but this is unintialized!
```

what is a decent/elegant way to solve this when designing a C++ library?
how do well-designed C++ libraries like Boost, Qt, etc solve this? any idea?

Comment: Look at [Solving the Static Initialization Order Fiasco (SIOF) with C++20](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-static-initialization-order-fiasco)

Comment: Probably the first step with "porting" a C library to C++ - before exploiting any C++-specific features - will be to simply compile with a C++ compiler (maybe, after adorning some functions/types with `extern "C"`). Types in a C library will not have constructors and, if a C++ compiler generates any (for `struct` types) they will either have no effect or give the same effect as in C.   If any issues with order of initialisation of globals arise when building as C++ then they probably existed but didn't show up in testing of the C version.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do - simply create a C wrapper interface for C++ I.e. something  like following:

In header file, e.g. foo.h

```
#ifndef __FOO_H_INCLUDED__
#define __FOO_H_INCLUDED__

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void print_logical_cpus()

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif / * extern "C"  */

#endif / * __FOO_H_INCLUDED__  */
```

in the implementation file e.g. foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>

struct GlobalSettings {
 GlobalSettings():
   logical_cpus(std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
 {}
  std::size_t logical_cpus;
};

static GlobalSettings __gsettings;

extern "C" {

  void print_logical_cpus()
  {
      std::printf("Logical cpus %z", __gsettings.logical_cpus);
  }

}
```

If you still need to port on raw C, there are compiler specific tricks to run functions before and after main.
GCC uses [**attribute**((constructor)) and **attribute**((destructor)))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work) 
MS VC++ uses [__declspec(allocate(".CRT$XLC"))](https://gist.github.com/vaualbus/4fb1e76e9a0f319534a745109b8c6078)