# Why does importing pandas seemingly spawn a process tree (one per logical core)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

When I import pandas with:

```
import pandas as pd
```

within my repl, and if I use htop and filter all the python processes, I can see that pandas spawns many processes on input, after exiting the interpreter, all the processes disappear.

Is there a reason for this behaviour? I've tried many versions ranging from 1.3.5 to 2.1.4 and this behaviour occurs in all the version I've tried. I've also tried a conda version and the same behaviour occurs.

I don't expect pandas to spawn processes.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is a thread being spawned per core (for whichever reason Pandas decides to), not a process.

`htop` shows threads by default ([more detail in this external article](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/htop-ps-more-processes)) and can color threads green (setup -> display options -> display threads in a different color) so they're easily distinguished; my hunch is you have that option turned off:

[image]

Digging a bit deeper, I built `strace` with `-k` (stack trace) support and:

```
# ./src/strace -o /dev/stdout -k python -c "import pandas" | grep -C40 pthread
[...snip...]
clone(child_stack=0xffff98bfea40, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tid=[2626], tls=0xffff98bff8c0, child_tidptr=0xffff98bff250) = 2626
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__clone+0x38) [0xe7e78]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(pthread_condattr_setpshared+0x114) [0x7ea54]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(pthread_create+0x4b0) [0x7f434]
 > /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblas64_p-r0-17488984.3.23.dev.so(blas_thread_init.part.0+0x10c) [0x27628c]
 > /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblas64_p-r0-17488984.3.23.dev.so(blas_thread_init+0x24) [0x2764a4]
 > /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblas64_p-r0-17488984.3.23.dev.so(gotoblas_init+0x70) [0xf0630]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1(__nptl_change_stack_perm+0xfdc) [0x431c]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1(__nptl_change_stack_perm+0x10e4) [0x4424]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_dl_catch_exception+0xc4) [0x12ecd4]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1(_dl_rtld_di_serinfo+0x2514) [0xa258]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_dl_catch_exception+0x6c) [0x12ec7c]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1(_dl_find_dso_for_object+0x17c) [0xa5fc]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(dlmopen+0x124) [0x7adf4]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_dl_catch_exception+0x6c) [0x12ec7c]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_dl_catch_error+0x40) [0x12ed40]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(dlerror+0x2c0) [0x7a880]
 > /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(dlopen+0x88) [0x7aec8]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(_PyImport_FindSharedFuncptr+0x98) [0x2d9d3c]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(_imp_create_dynamic+0x218) [0x2d6548]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL+0x68) [0x257058]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x6bfc) [0x1e9540]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(object_vacall+0x30c) [0x1fe7bc]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs+0xd0) [0x21e610]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject+0x2a8) [0x27a2e8]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x447c) [0x1e6dc0]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0xa4) [0x252534]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(builtin_exec+0x150) [0x281040]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL_KEYWORDS+0x70) [0x2532d0]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x6bfc) [0x1e9540]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(object_vacall+0x30c) [0x1fe7bc]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs+0xd0) [0x21e610]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject+0x2a8) [0x27a2e8]
 > /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.so.1.0(builtin___import__+0xb0) [0x286d00]
```

So it looks like it's happening while importing a module (this traceback doesn't tell me which) and `gotoblas_init` within `libopenblas` calls `blas_thread_init` initializes a bunch of worker threads. I also tried with `python -c "import numpy"`, and that reproduces this too, so it's not Pandas, but just Numpy.

[`gotoblas_init`](https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/blob/500442cf969d2a33d5b071b7b39309f78d0c8ac5/driver/others/memory.c#L1507) is defined with `CONSTRUCTOR` (an alias to `__attribute__ ((constructor))`), [which means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2053078/51685) the function is called automatically on shared library load.

[`blas_num_threads` is set here](https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/blob/500442cf969d2a33d5b071b7b39309f78d0c8ac5/driver/others/memory.c#L1219) and it looks like it reads [`openblas_num_threads_env()`](https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/blob/500442cf969d2a33d5b071b7b39309f78d0c8ac5/driver/others/openblas_env.c#L69-L78) if so configured... so putting all this newly learned information which probably didn't overwrite a happy childhood memory in my brain or anything together:

```
# env OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 python
Python 3.12.1 (main, Dec  9 2023, 00:02:46) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

and hey presto, no extra threads!

Oh, and in case you're interested exactly which Numpy module is importing OpenBLAS:

```
# python -v -c 'import numpy' 2>&1 | grep -E extens.+loaded
# extension module '_datetime' loaded from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_datetime.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' loaded from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module 'math' loaded from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/math.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module '_struct' loaded from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module '_pickle' loaded from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module '_contextvars' loaded from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_contextvars.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module 'numpy.core._multiarray_tests' loaded from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_tests.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so'
# extension module '_ctypes' loaded from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so'

# ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-312-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffff92f9e000)
    libopenblas64_p-r0-17488984.3.23.dev.so => /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libopenblas64_p-r0-17488984.3.23.dev.so (0x0000ffff91410000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000ffff91370000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000ffff91330000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff91180000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000ffff91150000)
    libgfortran-daac5196.so.5.0.0 => /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/../../numpy.libs/libgfortran-daac5196.so.5.0.0 (0x0000ffff90fd0000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffff92f61000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x0000ffff90f90000)
```

IOW, you can't really get away without importing OpenBLAS, since it's in `numpy.core._multiarray_umath`.

And in case you're wondering whether OpenBLAS *needs* to initialize the thread pool at `dlopen` time – no, it wouldn't need to, since [it already needs to check whether the pool is available every time it uses it, since a fork would destroy it](https://github.com/OpenMathLib/OpenBLAS/blob/500442cf969d2a33d5b071b7b39309f78d0c8ac5/driver/others/blas_server.c#L732-L735), so another(!) envvar to control whether the pool is eagerly initialized wouldn't be impossible.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes more sense. Still curious why pandas spawns all those threads on import.

Comment: @user3010969 WELL, GLAD YOU ASKED.  Please see my edit above.